# Spring Boot HttpServletRequest Request Scope Bean?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc

It would seem that `HttpServletRequest` is a request scope bean, but I have not yet been able to find any documentation on this.

Does anyone know where this is documented or where in the code base it is created?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `HttpServletRequest` is normally created and managed by servlet container (e.g. Tomcat) but not Spring. You normally do not need to define it as a spring bean unless you are doing something special. So technically from the spring 's point of view, the `HttpServletRequest` does not have any scope as it is not a spring bean.

But even if you need to define a `HttpServletRequest` bean for some reason, by default it will be in the singleton scope. (see the scope table in [this](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/reference/html/core.html#beans-factory-scopes)).

The relationship between `HttpServletRequest` and a request scope bean is that Spring will make sure whenever the servlet container process a new `HttpServletRequest` , it will create a new request scope bean instance in case you need to access it during processing this `HttpServletRequest`. And this request scope bean will be destroyed after the servlet container finish process that  `HttpServletRequest`. Such behaviour is also mentioned in the above link as :

> Scopes a single bean definition to the lifecycle of a single HTTP request. That is, each HTTP request has its own instance of a bean created off the back of a single bean definition. Only valid in the context of a web-aware Spring ApplicationContext